# How do I revert back to the default item renderer in a spark list after applying a custom item renderer?

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I have a flex spark list that is populated by a dynamically generated ArrayCollection (and is used in a recyclable component).  If the Array Collection is less than 9 items, a checkbox item renderer is applied.  If the ArrayCollection is greater than 8 items, I want to revert back to the default sparkList item Renderer.  How do I remove the itemRenderer from the spark list?

```
if ((ac.length>0)&&(ac.length <=8))
{
    //implement a renderer in the control for check boxes - this works!
    this._s_g_ListBoxLong._list.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(morris.renderers.Renderer_checkBoxes);
}
else if (ac.length >=9)
{
    //apply the default item renderer for a spark list or remove the itemRenderer pointer
    //?????  HOW DO I DO THIS?
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}
this._s_g_ListBoxLong._list.dataProvider = ac;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`DefaultItemRenderer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/spark/DefaultItemRenderer.html).

> The DefaultItemRenderer class defines the default item renderer for a List control. The default item renderer just draws the text associated with each item in the list.

```
this._s_g_ListBoxLong._list.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(DefaultItemRenderer);
```

Comment: That did the trick....Thanks, Sam!  For those of you who like literal code.... this._s_g_ListBoxLong._list.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer);